# I can't get the audio on my laptop to work correctly

Tags: sound, chromebook

I am running Elementary OS on an Acer Chromebook 15 (CB3-532). Everything worked fine but audio didn't work. I saw a post online that said to copy an asound.state file from a computer with Chrome OS or GalliumOS and copy that file to `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state`. and then run the following command `sudo alsa force-reload alsactl init sudo alsactl store --file /var/lib/alsa/asound.state sudo alsa force-reload`
My headphones are working now, but the speakers still doesn't work. Does anyone know what I can do so both my speakers and headphone jack work?

[Here's a link to my asound.state file just in case anyone wanted to see it.](https://pastebin.com/g7V9R13j)

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen on my Dell, though it's not a chromebook, but maybe a similar issue. Speakers work, but not the headphones, I was able to fix it by plugging in the headphones and executing `alsactl restore`

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with my computer speakers occures when I restart the PC from Windows into EOS. If I shut down the computer - when it starts again into eOS everything works well, but if I keep restarting - there is no sound into the speakers.

Try to shut it down, if you didn't already and check if it is ok when you start it again.